# I am having trouble figuring out the values of parameter passing

Tags: parameter-passing

what would be the outcome of calling the procedure using

a) Pass by value
b) Pass by reference
c) Pass by name
d) Pass by value-result

```
void main () {
int value = 2, list[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; swap (value, list[0]);
swap (list[0], list[1]);
swap (value, list[value]);
}
void swap (int a, int b) {
int temp;
temp = a; a = b;
b = temp;
}
```

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Comment: Trying it would answer your question, wouldn't it?

Comment: it is java I believe